# Laravel Seeding not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

Consider the below code:

```
foreach ($departments as $department)
        {
            factory(App\User::class, 100)->create()
            ->each(function ($u) use($department)
            {

                $u->employee()->save(factory(App\Employee::class)->make([
                    'department' => $department,
                    'emp_id' => '',
                ]));

            });

        }
```

Now for `emp_id` I want to have incremental value from **1 to 100** for each **iteration** of the **outer foreach loop**.

Example:

1st iteration 100 users and 100 employees record should be created with emp_id 1 to 100 with department as 'abc'

2nd iteration again 100 users and 100 employees record should be created with emp_id 1 to 100 with department as 'xyz'
and so on.

I tried to declare $i=1 before the factory and then increment $i withing `each()` but it did not work and gave `duplicate key error`.

> Note that the unique constraint in my table for employee is
>   department-emp_id

Comment: Do you have any (unique) constraints in place on one of these database tables (presumably `employees` table)?

Comment: I have mentioned that already at the end that I have a unique constraint on the combined columns department-emp_id together

Comment: Sorry, I totally overlooked it due to the color. Is `$department` an integer or a model?

Comment: $department is simply different name for departments like 'abc', 'xyz' and so on

Comment: I think your solution should work and it must be a minor detail that is causing troubles. Have you added the counting variable to the `use` part of your function within `each()`? Have you tried dumping the content of your counting variable within `each()`?

Comment: Yes I tried it. It always remains 1 which is the starting value and does not increment even if I do $i++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. The value of your index variable is not updating because when you pass primitives to a function in the `use` clause, they are copied. Only objects are passed by reference by default.

To get around this, you need to explicitely pass your index variable as reference by prepending an `&`:

```
foreach ($departments as $department)
{
    $i = 1;
    factory(App\User::class, 100)->create()
        ->each(function ($u) use ($department, &$i)
        {
            $u->employee()->save(factory(App\Employee::class)->make([
                'department' => $department,
                'emp_id' => $i++,
            ]));
        });
}
```

I hacked together a small example to show the difference over at [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/BWQi6).